# Custom URI routing with PHP - messes up onclick javascript calls

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess, routes

I'm using a WAMP stack and I've pieced together a custom routing function from code I've found online.  The idea was to allow a user to add their (or any) username to the end of the website root URL, and the router (index.php) would extract that username and serve up a customised home page.  Everything works fine in Firefox, but in Google Chrome the routing seems to mess up javascript function calls in the browser.  So a html element `onclick=someFunction()` looks for `someFunction()` at the wrong URL.

So, for example, say the user browses to my site, and appends their username to the url like - `www.example.com/@bruce`. The routing function (see index.php below) redirects to `www.example.com/somePage.php?q=bruce`. A page customised for Bruce is served up, but when Bruce clicks on an element with an `onclick` event, Chrome throws an error: `Uncaught TypeError: someFunction() is not a function at HTMLInputElement.onclick (VM509 somePage.php?q=@bruce:44)`

Any ideas how to get around this, so that I can still route my users?

Index.php:

```
<?php
//Router

    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $user = "";

    if(strpos($uri, "@") > 0) {
        $user = substr($uri, strpos($uri, "@"));
    }

    //do a validation on the user name before redirecting
    header('Location: somePage.php?q=' . $user);   //hardcode url here on deployment
    die();
?>
```

Here's my .htaccess file, if it's relevant (I copy pasta'd this from a stackoverflow answer on PHP routing):

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Edit to add the script paths in my somePage.php in case that's causing the problem:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>SomePage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./somePage.css">
    <script src="./somePage.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: First of all there seems to be some discrepancy between your urls. In the question here it becomes `q=bruce`, however in the error it's `q=@bruce`.

Comment: However these problems seem to be unrelated to each other is my guess. I think the redirected page doesn't have a JS-file loaded that contains `someFunction`

Comment: Hmm, I didn't notice that discrepancy.  the substr function must not be working as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I inadvertently had a couple of elements on my page with the same `id`.  Once I fixed that up, it started working fine in Chrome.  Interesting that it worked in FF and not Chrome originally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going on a Wild Hunt here ***wink***.

> **Uncaught TypeError: someFunction() is not a function at HTMLInputElement.onclick (VM509 somePage.php?q=@bruce:44)**

That means the function isn't in the global scope. That means the script block with this function is not present.

Make sure the script block containing `someFunction` is in `somepage.php`.

Comment: Well it works in Firefox, so it's there in that case.  Why would Chrome not retrieve it?